# conversion of PointCloud2 to pcl pointcloud using python

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS gurus,

I am working on python pcl and point clouds. Is there a way where i can convert sensor_msgs.msg/PointCloud2 type to PCL point cloud using python, so i can use PCL functions on the data.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236486/conversion-of-pointcloud2-to-pcl-pointcloud-using-python/) by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2016-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use this code even if it is in C++.. but I think you can write your own python version from it.

```
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/PCLPointCloud2.h>
#include <pcl/conversions.h>
#include <pcl_ros/transforms.h>

 void cloud_cb(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>& input){

    pcl::PCLPointCloud2 pcl_pc2;
    pcl_conversions::toPCL(*input,pcl_pc2);
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr temp_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(pcl_pc2,*temp_cloud);
    //do stuff with temp_cloud here
    }
```

---

Originally posted by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) with karma: 751 on 2016-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on 2016-06-10**:
Hey,

Thanks for the code. I already came across this code snippet, as i mentioned in my post i am looking for python version of it. Do you have a code snippet in python version that i can develop on. I am not really good at C++ and  in python with what modules should i import instead of .h files?